# Android 10 get path from Uri

Tags: video, path, uri, android-10.0

Hi I developed an app in which I am getting video path from Uri. In below 10 it is working fine in 11 also it is working fine, but in 10 if I don't give permission "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" dynamically I am not getting path from Uri if I give permission dynamically I am getting path from Uri. Below is the code to get path from Uri. I have already mentioned "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in manifest. I am getting uri like "content://com.android.providers.media.documents"

public String getPathFromURI(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

```
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            Uri contentUri=null;
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            if(id.startsWith("raw"))
            {
                return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
            }

                contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

So my Question is for video, should I ask "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" dynamically in android 10 or is there any  problem in code?

Comment: "In below 10 it is working fine" -- no, it is not. It will work in a few cases. It will fail in lots of others. Please use the `Uri` correctly, as an opaque identifier of content. You can use `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile` to work with `Uri` values, for things like reading and writing the content and obtaining metadata about that content.

Comment: @CommonsWare but when I give READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission dynamically that method is working. So is it necessary to ask permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE dynamically for 10 and above ?

Comment: "that method is working" -- for some subset of possible `Uri` values, for some users, on some devices, interacting with some apps, some of the time, yes. It is not going to be reliable for everything. **Please use the `Uri` correctly, as an opaque identifier of content.**

Comment: can you please provide any example..!!

Comment: [This book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) shows [this example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v2.0/Diceware/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/diceware/PassphraseRepository.java) and [this example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v2.0/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/TextRepository.java). [This book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore) shows [this example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v2.0/T29-Report/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/report/RosterReport.kt).